# How to create new array based on duplicate array values and calculate average?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a feedback system in which students enter feedback for teachers and then calculate the average for each class and respective subjects. How do I do that?

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [empName] => Shahrukh Khan
            [class] => Bachelor in Computer Applications 1st Year
            [subjectName] => Basic Mathematics
            [average] => 60
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [empName] => Shahrukh Khan
            [class] => Bachelor in Commerce 1st Year
            [subjectName] => Basic Mathematics
            [average] => 60
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [empName] => Anshu Sharma
            [class] => Bachelor in Computer Applications 1st Year
            [subjectName] => Operating System
            [average] => 75
        )

)
```

I am getting this as output.

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $query = $this->Admin_model->getFeedbackReport($value->emp_uid,$value->subjectId,$month,$this->feedback1);

        $excel = 0; $good = 0; $fair = 0;
        foreach ($query as $key => $val) {
            if($val->rating == "Excellent")
                $excel = $excel+1;
            elseif($val->rating == "Good")
                $good = $good+1;     
            else
                $fair = $fair+1;

        }
        $finalAverage =0;
        //echo $excel."<br>"; echo $good."<br>"; echo $fair;
        $total = $excel+$good+$fair;
        $excelWeight = $excel * 2;
        $goodWeight = $good * 1;
        $fairWeight = $fair * 0;
        $marksGained = $excelWeight+$goodWeight+$fairWeight;
        $maxScore = $total*2;
        $average = round($marksGained/$maxScore * 100); 
        $data[]= array(
            'empName'       => $value->emp_name, 
            'class'         => $value->course_name." ".$value->class_name,
            'subjectName'   => $value->subjectName,
            'average'       => $average
        );
    }        
    //print_r($data);
```

I expect that wherever empName is same the average (i.e:60) gets to add and average is calculated (i.e 60+60/2).

Expected Output -

```
+------+---------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+
| S.No |     Name      |                 Class                 |        Subject        | Average | Final |
+------+---------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+
|    1 | Shahrukh khan |  Bachelor in Commerce 1st Year        | Basic Mathematics     |      60 |    60 |
|    2 | Anshu Sharma  | Bachelor in Computer Applications 1st | Year Operating System |      75 |    75 |
+------+---------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: is `class` neccessary on your output or not?

Comment: yes. It is neccessary

Comment: **average is calculated (i.e 60+60/2)** it depends on which field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, `Sunject`, `Class` and `Average` can repeat as I see.

This solution is based on collection `unique empNames`, handling `index` of the first appearence and summing average values.

Plase `$ar_emp = []; $ar_s = [];` before `foreach` statement and then replace:

```
$data[]= array(
    'empName'       => $value->emp_name, 
    'class'         => $value->course_name." ".$value->class_name,
    'subjectName'   => $value->subjectName,
    'average'       => $average
);
```

with code below:

```
$val_ename = $value->emp_name;
$val_class = $value->course_name." ".$value->class_name;
$val_sname = $value->subjectName;
$val_avera = $average;

if (!in_array($val_ename, $ar_emp)) { 

    array_push($ar_emp, $val_ename); 

    $ar_s[$val_ename] = array (
          'coun'      => 1,
          'average'   => $val_avera,
          'inde'      => $key 
    );

    $data[]= array(
        'empName'       => $val_ename, 
        'class'         => $val_class,
        'subjectName'   => $val_sname,
        'last_average'  => $val_avera,
        'final'         => $val_avera
    ); 

} else {

    $ar_s[$val_ename]['coun'] += 1;
    $ar_s[$val_ename]['average'] += $val_avera;

    $data[$ar_s[$val_ename]['inde']]= array(
                    'empName'       => $val_ename, 
                    'class'         => $val_class,
                    'subjectName'   => $val_sname,
                    'last_average'  => $val_avera,
                    'final'         => ($ar_s[$val_ename]['average'] / $ar_s[$val_ename]['coun'])
    );               
}
```

Comment: It is calculating the average but it is also storing the first average.                        
 [avg] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [empName] => Shahrukh Khan
                    [final] => 50
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [empName] => Shahrukh Khan
                    [final] => 62.5
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [empName] => Anshu Sharma
                    [final] => 67
                )

        ) @Aksen P

Comment: @AnshuSharma, it can't, cause it stores `unique empNames`, perhaps there're exists spaces in some `empNames`. Try to add `trim()` like this -> `trim($value->emp_name)` and check it one more time. Result array **must** containing the only one record for each one `empName`. It can't has more than one record for one `empName`.